# crosscompiled OpenCV, runtime Error: The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support

Tags: opencv

I want to run a opencv binary coded with c++ on my target platform(aarch64 architecture). so i tried first cross compilation opencv on my host computer(linux with x86 architecture).

I followed this [post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-ultimate-opencv-cross-compilation-guide-for-embedded-processors-f2fdc8ccb7b2) as my example.

I used this cmake command to build my opencv:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch64-gnu.toolchain.cmake.cmake ..
```

> Note: C++ runs with no error on my host computer

but after i compiled the C++ code with this opencv libs and try to run my binary on my target platform, this problem occurs:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  ..modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:516: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvNamedWindow
```

so i tried compilation again with cmake code:

```
cmake -DHIGHGUI_PLUGIN_LIST=all \
      -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch64-gnu.toolchain.cmake ..
```

the code `-DHIGHGUI_PLUGIN_LIST=all` is for backends gtk, gtk2, gtk3, if i understand correctly from [opencv config reference](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html#:%7E:text=support%20for%20details.-,highgui%20plugins,-Since%20OpenCV%204.5.3).

but it still did not work out.

here is my cmake output:

```
...
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FSIGNED_CHAR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_W - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WALL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WRETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WRETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WRETURN_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WRETURN_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WADDRESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WADDRESS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSEQUENCE_POINT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSEQUENCE_POINT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WFORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT_SECURITY
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WFORMAT_SECURITY - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_COMMENT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WIMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH_3 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_OVERFLOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_PTHREAD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FOMIT_FRAME_POINTER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FFUNCTION_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDATA_SECTIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_NEON_SUPPORT (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_neon.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_NEON_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_FP16_SUPPORT (check file: cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp)
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_FP16_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CPU_BASELINE_FLAGS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_AS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_AS_NEEDED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_NO_UNDEFINED
-- Performing Test HAVE_LINK_NO_UNDEFINED - Success
-- OpenCV disables pkg-config to avoid using of host libraries. Consider using PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR to specify target SYSROOT
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - found
-- Looking for malloc.h
-- Looking for malloc.h - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.2.3")
-- Looking for fseeko
-- Looking for fseeko - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Check size of off64_t
-- Check size of off64_t - failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ATTRIBUTES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_STRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHIFT_NEGATIVE_VALUE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHIFT_NEGATIVE_VALUE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.1.2, BUILD = opencv-4.6.0-dev-libjpeg-turbo
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of unsigned long
-- Check size of unsigned long - done
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZL
-- Performing Test HAVE_BUILTIN_CTZL - Success
-- Looking for include file locale.h
-- Looking for include file locale.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h
-- Looking for include file stdlib.h - found
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h
-- Looking for include file sys/types.h - found
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Looking for assert.h
-- Looking for assert.h - found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for io.h
-- Looking for io.h - not found
-- Looking for limits.h
-- Looking for limits.h - found
-- Looking for memory.h
-- Looking for memory.h - found
-- Looking for search.h
-- Looking for search.h - found
-- Looking for string.h
-- Looking for string.h - found
-- Looking for strings.h
-- Looking for strings.h - found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
-- Looking for sys/time.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Performing Test C_HAS_inline
-- Performing Test C_HAS_inline - Success
-- Check size of signed short
-- Check size of signed short - done
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Check size of signed int
-- Check size of signed int - done
-- Check size of unsigned int
-- Check size of unsigned int - done
-- Check size of signed long
-- Check size of signed long - done
-- Check size of signed long long
-- Check size of signed long long - done
-- Check size of unsigned long long
-- Check size of unsigned long long - done
-- Check size of unsigned char *
-- Check size of unsigned char * - done
-- Check size of ptrdiff_t
-- Check size of ptrdiff_t - done
-- Check size of INT8
-- Check size of INT8 - failed
-- Check size of INT16
-- Check size of INT16 - failed
-- Check size of INT32
-- Check size of INT32 - failed
-- Looking for floor
-- Looking for floor - found
-- Looking for pow
-- Looking for pow - found
-- Looking for sqrt
-- Looking for sqrt - found
-- Looking for isascii
-- Looking for isascii - found
-- Looking for memset
-- Looking for memset - found
-- Looking for mmap
-- Looking for mmap - found
-- Looking for getopt
-- Looking for getopt - found
-- Looking for memmove
-- Looking for memmove - found
-- Looking for setmode
-- Looking for setmode - not found
-- Looking for strcasecmp
-- Looking for strcasecmp - found
-- Looking for strchr
-- Looking for strchr - found
-- Looking for strrchr
-- Looking for strrchr - found
-- Looking for strstr
-- Looking for strstr - found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtol
-- Looking for strtol - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for lfind
-- Looking for lfind - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF
-- Performing Test HAVE_SNPRINTF - Success
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_BUT_SET_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_ALIGN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_POINTER_TO_INT_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_INT_TO_POINTER_CAST - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MISLEADING_INDENTATION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ARRAY_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_ARRAY_PARAMETER - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_PARAMETER - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_STD_C99
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_STD_C99 - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Could NOT find OpenJPEG (minimal suitable version: 2.0, recommended version >= 2.3.1). OpenJPEG will be built from sources
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_CONST_INT_FLOAT_CONVERSION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_IMPLICIT_CONST_INT_FLOAT_CONVERSION - Failed
-- OpenJPEG: VERSION = 2.4.0, BUILD = opencv-4.6.0-dev-openjp2-2.4.0
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for stdio.h
-- Looking for stdio.h - found
-- Looking for math.h
-- Looking for math.h - found
-- Looking for float.h
-- Looking for float.h - found
-- Looking for time.h
-- Looking for time.h - found
-- Looking for stdarg.h
-- Looking for stdarg.h - found
-- Looking for ctype.h
-- Looking for ctype.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
-- Looking for inttypes.h - found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - found
-- Looking for include file malloc.h
-- Looking for include file malloc.h - found
-- Looking for _aligned_malloc
-- Looking for _aligned_malloc - not found
-- Looking for posix_memalign
-- Looking for posix_memalign - found
-- Looking for memalign
-- Looking for memalign - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_FUNCTION_TYPE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_CAST_FUNCTION_TYPE - Success
-- OpenJPEG libraries will be built from sources: libopenjp2 (version "2.4.0")
-- Found ZLIB: zlib (found version "1.2.12")
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NULL_POINTER_SUBTRACTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NULL_POINTER_SUBTRACTION - Failed
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY)
-- Looking for sgemm_
-- Looking for sgemm_ - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)
-- LAPACK requires BLAS
-- A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_LOCAL_TYPEDEFS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_TAUTOLOGICAL_UNDEFINED_COMPARE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IGNORED_QUALIFIERS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED_CONST_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHORTEN_64_TO_32 - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INVALID_OFFSETOF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ENUM_COMPARE_SWITCH - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SUGGEST_OVERRIDE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_INCONSISTENT_MISSING_OVERRIDE - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_IMPLICIT_FALLTHROUGH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_CLASS_MEMACCESS - Success
-- Looking for dlerror in dl
-- Looking for dlerror in dl - found
-- ADE: Downloading v0.1.1f.zip from https://github.com/opencv/ade/archive/v0.1.1f.zip
-- Allocator metrics storage type: 'int'
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse3.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.ssse3.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.sse4_2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin128.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin256.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/core/test/test_intrin512.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/corner.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.sse4_1.cpp
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/dnn/src/layers/fast_convolution/fast_convolution.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.rvv.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/int8layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/int8layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- highgui: using builtin backend: NONE
-- Found 'misc' Python modules from /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/modules/python/package/extra_modules
-- Found 'mat_wrapper;utils' Python modules from /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/modules/core/misc/python/package
-- Found 'gapi' Python modules from /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/modules/gapi/misc/python/package
--
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.6.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               4.6.0-91-gc3cbd302cb
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2022-08-12T11:12:26Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64
--     Target:                      Linux 1 aarch64
--     CMake:                       3.16.3
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    NEON FP16
--       required:                  NEON
--       disabled:                  VFPV3
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ standard:                11
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++  (ver 9.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fdata-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Wreturn-type -Waddress -Wsequence-point -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java python2 python3
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   GUI:                           NONE
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+:                        NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.12)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.2-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.19.1)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/yiwei/Documents/src_packages/opencv/build
```

sorry for the long text. but GTK did not show yes in configuration output.

Can anyone give some detailed tipps?
thx.

Comment: You get this  GUI:                           NONE
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+:                        NO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still cannot address the error, but i managed to install opencv directly on my target platform.

maybe this solution could help you.

Due to limit computing power of our target platform. We need to make sure which opencv libraries are used in our program.

1. We need to build a example binary(with x86 compiled) on our host computer, which can be executed on our host computer. Then we need to check its needed libraries from opencv.

```
#in terminal
ldd <your binary name>
```

2. after you get your required libraries, you need to install them from source on your target platform. [you can check it here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html#:%7E:text=../opencv-,Build%20limited%20set%20of%20modules,-Each%20module%20is)

```
# Download and unpack sources
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip
unzip opencv.zip

# create build folder
cd opencv
mkdir -p build && cd build

# cmake with limit modules. 
cmake -DBUILD_LIST=<module1>,<module2> ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```

3. **ATTENTION**: Something may go wrong with make, so you just have to install required packages on your target platform. In my case, i have to uninstall "libopenjp2-7" and reinstall it in order to make "imgcodecs" function compile successfully.

I hope this may help you. :D